# RequireJs and Custom JS file blur

Tags: magento2, jquery, requirejs

this is my simple requirejs-config.js file

```
 var config = {
            deps: ['js/custom']
        };
```

and this is my custom.js file

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "domReady!"
], 
function($) {
    "use strict";
    $("input").blur(function(){
        alert("This input field has lost its focus.");
    }); 
});
```

why blur alert does not works?

But if i call it with an event it works?

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
       $("input").blur(function(){
            alert("This input field has lost its focus.");
        }); 
    });
```

Also other jquery function does not works on domready and i need to call it with an event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing your DOM structure, my guess is the `input` is rendered via JS (most of the checkout/minicart is) so it hasn't actually loaded at the point you add your event handler. If this is the problem using event delegation should resolve this:

Try this:

```
$("body").on("blur", "input", function(){
    alert("This input field has lost its focus.");
});
```

It's good practice to change body to the closest parent element that is not rendered via JS.

For more info on event delegation see here - https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: works fine thanks! is there a way to use an event delegation also for select2? $('select').select2();

Comment: You can add more elements into the second argument, for example replace `"input"` with `#selector1, #selector2, .class1` etc.

Comment: but i cannot use "blur" with a div? I need to start select 2 in every pages witch event listener can i use?

Comment: I rarely use blur so I'm not too sure sorry, you could try the focusout event in jQuery - https://api.jquery.com/focusout/